# push an apk file into assets folder programmatically in android

Tags: java, android

Can i push an apk file into my assests folder programmatically?I wanted to use this apk file 
in my application.

Please forward your valuable suggestions to me.

Thanks in advance...
Priya

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674535/programatically-save-apk-file-from-asset-folder-to-system-app-in-android

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't store it in the assets directory. However you can store is some where on the sdcard or cache directory. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for different data storage methods available.